# Is there a way to find out the width of someones screen on there computer using javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web site that has 4 different pages loaded, 3 are hidden and only 1 shows at any given time. When the navigation is clicked, the page switches by scrolling.

I want to fix the navigation bar horizontally in the centre of the screen.

See the general idea [here](http://tragicclothing.co.uk/mitchell%20design/index.html)

---

So I need a way to find the width of the **window** (although I don't want it to change if the user changes the width of the window. So I think I might mean screen?) so lets say `var width = what I am looking for window width or screen width`

And then I want to have the css:

```
#myDiv1 {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
color:#fff;
}

#myDiv2 {
position:absolute;
left: !!-- width --!! px;
top:0px;
color:#fff;
}

#myDiv3 {
position:absolute;
left: 2 * !!-- width --!! px;
top:0px;
color:#fff;
}
```

And then to hyperlink each of the links which is centred in the middle of the screen

```
#navigation{
position: fixed;
left: 0.5 * !!-- width --!! px;
}
```

Comment: Any responsive framework [bootstrap, pure, skeleton] would do.

Comment: @Popnoodles Have you looked at the link by what I mean for '4 separate pages'?

Comment: erm I will explain it: I have 1 html page. But the width is very large. And has 4 separate parts (horizontally): Home, About, Contacts, Projects. I want to be able to navigate to these using a hyperlink.

Comment: Yes code needed @user2768038. If you havnt read ***how to ask*** then let me tell you that code is needed becoz a site may not be accessible or present in the future then the later users will not be able to understand your Question because your link you provided may not exists.

Comment: Just one question: do you mean screen (the monitor) or the width of the browser window which may not be full screen?

Comment: Sorry @Popnoodles The browser window.

Comment: @Popnoodles I was thinking of getting the width then multiplying by 2 for the second page, 3 for the third, etc. And then using hyperlink points `$(document).ready(function(){ 
    

    
$("a#about1").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollLeft: $("a#myDiv1").offset().left   }, 2000);

 
});
});`

Comment: Right, I see what you mean now. What's wrong with what you've done?

Comment: Can you see updated answer? @Popnoodles

Comment: @user2768038 check out my update below, I think it's what you're looking for, it will adjust the sections per the users window width on page load.

Comment: Ok your question is clearer. You still don't need Javascript, you can center align using CSS. Have your menu in a wrapper and set the CSS to `width: 25%, position: fixed; text-align:center;`

Answer (score 4):

You can get the size of the user's screen with:

```
screen.width
screen.height
```

You can find out the available size (ie. not including the taskbar)

```
screen.availWidth
screen.availHeight
```

There's a number of other useful properties there too, depending on what you need.

If it's the window's size you want, try:

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

Just be sure to consider if this is what you want.

```
<div style="width:500px;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid black">I'm in the middle!</div>
```

Comment: Sorry is this javascript? I don't quite understand the answer?

Comment: This is because your question does not explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

yeah use

```
$(window).width();
```

you can store it in a variable and adjust the css with it.

**UPDATE**
check out the fiddle below, I think this is what you are looking for

```
var findWidth = $(window).width();

$(".container").css({"width":(findWidth*4)+"px"});
$(".section").css({"width":(findWidth)+"px"});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TLu5E/3/)

Comment: the window size is different from screen size

Comment: just check the question out: Is there a way to find out **the width of someones screen on there computer**

Comment: yeah but i think they meant window, they just used the term "screen".

Comment: it has again been mentioned **the width of the persons computer screen**, it is totally clear though.

Comment: it's because a non-coder doesn't understand the word "window", they would refer to it as screen

Comment: Sorry About that guys: hungover on new years day! @Popnoodles is correct!

Comment: @Popnoodles I gave up. totally agree, I got my vote down back, and voted down the question.

Comment: @Popnoodles: please edit your answer, add anything like space or a point, to let me get my vote down back.

Comment: @MehranHatami it's not my answer

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp the screen.width variable returns the screen width.

```
var x = "Total Width: " + screen.width;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
```

But there are templates that will do that for you. A good place to start is to search for 'responsive web design' on Google.

Answer (score 0):

May be below fiddle may help you in creating http://tragicclothing.co.uk/mitchell%20design/index.html type page :

Using JQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/RL84x/

```
var total=$(window).width()*4;
$('.color').css({'width':''+$(window).width()+''});
$('.1').css({'position':'absolute','left':'0px'});
$('.2').css({'position':'absolute','left':''+$(window).width()+'px'});
$('.3').css({'position':'absolute','left':''+$(window).width()*2+'px'});
$('.4').css({'position':'absolute','left':''+$(window).width()*3+'px'});


$('a').click(function(){
var num=$(this).attr('id');
$('html').animate({'scrollLeft':''+$(window).width()*num+''});
});
```